# EMF of an ideal cell

Tags: voltage, batteries

I know it's a very stupid question but I am confused a little bit right now.

An ideal cell has constant EMF of 7V. When connected in a circuit, the voltage across the cell decreases to 5V.

Can i say that the new EMF of the cell is 5V?

please consider the cell as a non-ideal cell

Comment: Not sure what you mean by *ideal cell* if the voltage across depends on the current through.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In an ideal cell the internal resistance is zero.  According to the equation
$V=E-Ir$  the $I*r$ term is always zero for an ideal cell.  So, there can not be any voltage drop across the cell after connecting to a circuit that means $V$ is always equal to EMF.